# How to call observer in controller

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, event-observer

I want to call  observer in controller using `if condition` this is my code

`app\code\local\EPayment\EPayment\controllers\IndexController.php`

```
class EPayment_EPayment_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function getepaymentAction()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $left_amount = $params['left_amount'];
        if($left_amount == true){
          // call observer here
           $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
          $this->getResponse()->setBody($left_amount);
        }
    }
}
```

`app\code\local\EPayment\EPayment\Model\Observer.php`

```
class EPayment_EPayment_Model_Observer
{
    public function setDiscount($observer)
    {
        // some codes here
    }
}
```

The above code `$left_amount` is `true` call `Observer.php`.

> **Note:** I write code for set discount in `Observer.php`.

Comment: You Observer.php file is located inside Model folder !  Can you please confirm you want to use Model or Observer ?

Comment: @MGento: Thanks for reply i want Observer because am trying to set discount by code

Comment: Use the dependency injection way to access the function from your Observer.php file, inside your controller

Comment: @MGento: Like this `Mage::getModel('epayment/observer')->getAlert();`

Comment: @MGento: Am using magento 1.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dispatch event you have to write:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('YOUR_EVENT_NAME', [YOUR_DATA]);
```

For example:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('my_event', ['order' => $order]);
```

You should put this code inside of if in controller.
Then you must configure event listener in etc/config.xml:

```
<events>
  <my_event>
    <observers>
      <some_fancy_observer_name>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>EPayment_EPayment_Model_Observer</class>
        <method> setDiscount </method>
      </some_fancy_observer_name>
     </observers>
  </some_fancy_observer_name>
</events>
```

And then put required logic inside of your observer.

Comment: Bro thanks its working i mean discount price apply. But here am creating `button` if i click button apply discount else discount don't apply

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate or preferably ask new question?

Comment: Sure bro i will ask new one. will accept your answer here

Comment: bro see this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205026/set-discount-price-without-using-coupon-in-magento-1-9