# Set discount price without using coupon in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, coupon, event-observer

Am trying to set discount `price` without using `coupon`. Discount apply but i have creating a `checkbox` in `checkout/onepage` if i click checkbox discount apply else discount don't apply here.

[image]

**Following my code:**

**PHTML:**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 2px 15px;">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input id="epayment" value="" type="checkbox" name="payment[method]" title="Payment By Your EPayment" onclick=""  class="pull-left" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
               Payment By EPayment     
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body collapse" id="demo">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Payment To Be Made</label>
                <input type="text" name="cart_amount" id="cart_amount" value="1900">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Your Balance Amount</label>
                <input type="text" name="epayment_amount" id="epayment_amount" value="2000">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label id="left_amount_label">Left Amount To Be Pay</label>
                <input type="text" name="left_amount" id="left_amount" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ajax for subtract grand total -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#epayment').click(function() {
        var result = document.getElementById('cart_amount').value;
        var mageurl = "<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>epayment/index/getepayment";
        jQuery.ajax({
            url     : mageurl,
            type    : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data    : {"cart_amount" : result},
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }});
    });
</script>
<!-- ajax for subtract grand total -->
```

**Controller:**

```
class EPayment_EPayment_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
  public function getepaymentAction()
  {
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $cart_amount = $params['cart_amount'];
    if($cart_amount > 0){
      //Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_collect_totals_after', array('cart_amount' => $cart_amount));
      Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_collect_totals_after', ['cart_amount' => $cart_amount]);
      $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      $this->getResponse()->setBody($cart_amount);
    }
  }
}
```

**Model/Observer:**

```
class EPayment_EPayment_Model_Observer
{

public function setDiscount($observer)
{
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
  $cart_amount = $quote->getBaseSubtotal();
  $quoteid = $quote->getId();

  $discountAmount = $total;
   // some code here
   // ...
   // ...
}
}
```

I have pass `cart_amount` using `ajax`, And then get `ajax` data in controller.

Comment: Why dont you use Catalog or cart rules without coupons?

Comment: @KonradSiamro: i have already run one coupon code here thats why

Comment: And am trying to create like wallet system link here http://magento.webkul.com/magento-modules-demo/index.php/demomanagement/demo/viewdemo/demoid/12/

Comment: You can use multiple promotions (with and without coupons). Just You have to disable "Stop Further Rules Processing" . I see. And you would like to create static promotion for user using ewalet?

Comment: @KonradSiamro: Did you see this link http://magento.webkul.com/magento-modules-demo/index.php/customer/account/login/